# Why am I getting the wrong timer frequency in PIC microcontroller application?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, mplab

I am getting results I don't understand in a small application (I am still a learner) using PIC16F627A MCU.  Schematic of the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAfrD4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The C source code I have is as follows:

```
// CONFIG
#pragma config FOSC = INTOSCIO  // Oscillator Selection bits (INTOSC oscillator: I/O function on RA6/OSC2/CLKOUT pin, I/O function on RA7/OSC1/CLKIN)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT enabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // RA5/MCLR/VPP Pin Function Select bit (RA5/MCLR/VPP pin function is MCLR)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out Detect Enable bit (BOD disabled)
#pragma config LVP = OFF        // Low-Voltage Programming Enable bit (RB4/PGM pin has digital I/O function, HV on MCLR must be used for programming)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EE Memory Code Protection bit (Data memory code protection off)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit (Code protection off)

#include <xc.h>

#define GPIO_OUTPUT 0
#define GPIO_INPUT 1

#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

#define RED_LED PORTAbits.RA1
#define YELLOW_LED PORTBbits.RB3

#define TIMER_RESET_VALUE 206; 


long time_count;
long time_threshold = 10;  // 10 x 0.1ms = 1ms = 1kHz
long time_count_max_value = 20000;  // some sort of cutoff

void reset_timer() {
    TMR0 = TIMER_RESET_VALUE;
}

void __interrupt() isr(void) {
    //reset the interrupt flag
    INTCONbits.T0IF = 0;  // Clear the TMR0 interrupt flag
    RED_LED = ~RED_LED;   // flip the RED_LED bit
    
    reset_timer();
    time_count++;
    if (time_count >= time_count_max_value) {
        time_count = 0;
    }    
}


void timer_initialise() {
    OPTION_REGbits.PSA = 0;     //Prescaler assigned to Timer 0 

    OPTION_REGbits.PS = 0b000;  //Set the prescaler to 1:2 
    OPTION_REGbits.T0CS = 0;    //Use the instruction clock (Fcy/4) as the timer
                                //clock. 

    INTCONbits.T0IF = 0;        //Clear the Timer 0 interrupt flag
    reset_timer();              //Load initial value into the timer
    INTCONbits.T0IE = 1;        //Enable the Timer 0 interrupt    
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;         //Set the Global Interrupt Enable
}




void main(void) {

    // TRISA = 0xFF; // default all GPIO as inputs
    // TRISB = 0xFF; // default all GPIO as inputs
    
    TRISA1 = GPIO_OUTPUT; // red LED is output
    TRISB3 = GPIO_OUTPUT; // yellow LED is output
    YELLOW_LED = 0; // start with LED off
    RED_LED = 1; // start with RED_LED on
    
    timer_initialise();
    
    while (1) {
        if (time_count == time_threshold/2) {
            time_count = 0;
            YELLOW_LED = ~YELLOW_LED;
        }
    }
    
    return;
}
```

I am using MPLAB X IDE 5.40 with XC8 v2.41 compiler.

The results I get are:

1. The yellow LED blinks at a frequency of 850 Hz instead of the 1 kHz I was trying to achieve
2. The red LED remains on constantly instead of blinking at the 10kHz I was trying to achieve

Both were measured with oscilloscope and DMM.

I realise the objective is pretty benign but it's just an exercise I am going through to learn and practice basic concepts.

Comment: Could 1) be an off-by-one error?

Comment: Ah!  Could be!  With prescaler at 1:2 you're right, I recall there should be an adjustment  of 1.  Let me try...

Comment: I'd write that as an answer, but I don't think I can help with 2), so it'd be an incomplete answer.

Comment: Is this a chip where the comparator is active by default? If you want RA1 to be a digital I/O, you might try disabling the comparator...CMCON=0x07. Haven't used this chip, so am unsure - this addresses the constantly-ON RED LED.

Comment: OK regarding (1)... in fact I believe there are two off-by-one problems... In the main while() loop I have been careless at when the YELLOW_LED is switched.  I have forced it to switch when time_count == 4.  This brings the frequeny of YELLOW_LED to 950 Hz (not sure if that's good enough but it's an explanation)  Maybe there's some slippage in the instruction cycle as well?  I will try disabling the prescaler.  Regarding TMR0, it of course makes a small difference but I need to go back to the theory to know exactly what is the correct value.

Comment: @glen_geek, I was trying to figure something like that out from the datasheet but couldn't find it explicitly.  Will try...

Comment: @glen_geek.  OK I found in datasheet that value of CMCON on POR/any reset is 0x00.  Which by inference from your comment, is default active.  Therefore, yes, setting CMCON = 0x07 has solved the problem.

Comment: And disabling the prescaler and setting TIMER_RESET VALUE = 206 improves the frequency of YELLOW_LED to 975 Hz which is 2.5% off which should be fine.  I can only increase the clock frequency on this chip externally.

Comment: Correction: TIMER_RESET_VALUE = 158

Comment: Only remaining puzzle is why RED_LED blinks at 3.9kHz instead of 5kHz (conjecture in question was wrong)?

Comment: This is an 8 bit MCU and you use variables of type long, which need 4 memory read cycles to fetch the value. But the interrupt code may modify such a value in the middle of a read access of the main loop. Such variables must be declared as "volatile" and the access in the main thread must be surrounded by disable and enable interrupt calls.

Comment: OK, that's a very insightful comment...  better, I infer, to use types int or smaller instead

Comment: Changed type long to unsigned short - results unchanged.  YELLOW_LED still close to 1kHz, but RED_LED still @ 3.9kHz instead of 5kHz that I thought I would see.  But nonetheless I'm grateful for the insight, thanks.  I'm struggling to see why YELLOW behaves close to expected, but RED is far off.

Comment: You might try using the software simulator to track the cause of the problem. The PICkit hardware debugger could be used as well.

Comment: @PStechPaul: I would LOVE to be using a debugger.  I tried to use the MPLAB debugger with my PICkit 3.  But I had a horrible time.  Some sort of error at every step.  I went through all the steps in the Microchip docs, including their troubleshooters and got nowhere.  On fora the best answer I could find was "your chip may not have debugging capabilities".  At that point I went back to the sledgehammer approach and thought I would postpone using a debugger until I felt like learning more.  Perhaps that will be my next cry for help in this forum!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When TMR0 overflows, its interrupt is triggered, while TMR0 merrily keeps incrementing every microsecond...TMR0 has already incremented some few # counts before it gets reset to its new value.

- Since interrupts act like a **CALL**, TMR0 has already incremented by *at least* two at the beginning of interrupt routine.
- Flipping the RED LED takes *at least* another microsecond, and increments TMR0 by another count.
- Calling `reset_timer()` is another call - 2 more microseconds, and 2 more TMR0 counts
- Actually writing the new value to TMR0 takes another microsecond.

There may be more microseconds lost if the interrupt routine saves W and flags. All these extra microseconds extend the time between TMR0 writes (which lowers the frequency)

In any case, you should likely change `reset_timer()`

```
void reset_timer() {
    TMR0 -= TIMER_RESET_VALUE;
}
```

Or change the interrupt routine:

```
    void __interrupt() isr(void) {
    TMR0 -= TIMER_RESET_VALUE;
    //reset the interrupt flag
    INTCONbits.T0IF = 0;  // Clear the TMR0 interrupt flag
    RED_LED = ~RED_LED;   // flip the RED_LED bit
    time_count++;
    if (time_count >= time_count_max_value) {
       time_count = 0;
       }
    }
```

EDIT:
Subtracting a constant from a running timer can miss or add counts, depending on when the subtract actually takes effect. I cobbled up this interrupt structure in ASM (since I don't trust micro-compilers) to see if pipeline or other timing issues affect TMR0 period.

I would have guessed that **TIMER_RESET_VALUE** would be near 100 to interrupt every 100 microseconds. But subtracting a value of 97 resulted in 100us interrupt period - it seems that TMR0 stalls a few counts after the subtract...at least that's what MPLAB's Simulator tells me.
A compiled ISR may operate differently, requiring a tweak to TIMER_RESET_VALUE. If more predictable delays are required, the whole LED-flashing process would be better done in PWM mode with TMR2...using PR2 to set the period. NO ISR required to flash the RED LED. It is a more-complex thing to configure.

---

For some reason, Microchip thinks users prefer to use the two internal comparators, which over-rides the use of PORTA GPIO least-two-significant bits.
So if you want to use **RA0** or **RA1** as general-purpose I/0, you must disable comparator function by setting **CMCON=0x07**, rather than its power-on default of **0x00**.

Multi-function I/O pins are a pain to re-configure, but add versatility. MPLAB X IDE 5.4 may do the reconfiguration for you, if you use all its configuration features.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, lots of very useful info.  I wonder whether:
a) the reset should be TMR += TMR_RESET_VALUE
b) the reset should be the last line of the ISR

I did this and I now have both LEDs only 1% off-target.

(Agree about the use of PWM - this exercise was simply one for me to learn the use of timers and their interrupts - the ultimate application requires it)

Comment: RickyBoy - "-=" or "+=" as you please. When you leave home, do you count the kilometers from home, or kilometers to your destination? Consider code readability for someone else. Slightly safer to add/subtract TMR0 early in the ISR while its count value is low, to avoid potential math overflow if TMR_RESET_VALUE approaches 255.

Comment: Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

I was able to load and run the OP's original project, and the simulator stopwatch shows the timer interrupt occurring at 133 us intervals. The yellow LED toggles with about 660-675 us. The PICkit3 is in the list of available debuggers.

This is primarily to see that the project will run using the simulator.

[image: MPLABX IDE]

Comment: Thanks to you I am able to use the debugger now.  I feel I should share the code I now have (with all the great tips and advice I have been given) which works perfectly as far as I know.  But being new to this forum should I submit it as an answer, or an edit to the original post?